# Not able to refer the index inside the range function in yaml files

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I am trying dynamically assigning the values from separate values.yaml file to a variable.

My values.yaml file content

```
peer_cidr1 = x
peer_cidr2 = y
peer_cidr3 = z
```

Yaml file:

```
   {{- $root := . -}}
   {{ range $i, $dn := until (atoi (printf "%d" (int64 .Values.no_of_peers))) }}
   { "dst": "{{ $root.Values.peer_cidr$i }}" }
```

Referring as Values.peer_cidr$i to refer variables from values.yaml.
$i is throwing bad character error.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the content of you helm file, not yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$root.Values.peer_cidr$i` is invalid syntax in templates.

Instead use the `index` function, e.g.

```
{{ index $root "Values" (printf "peer_cidr%d" $i) }}
```

Also note that the index stats at `0` but the values you want to look up start at `1` (e.g. `peer_cidr1`), so the value for index `0` will not exist, and you will not visit the last element. So add 1 to the `$i` like this:

```
{{ index $root "Values" (printf "peer_cidr%d" (add1 $i) ) }}
```

Comment: @Balaganesh.V Then consider upvoting and accepting the answer.